# jUnit mocking ModelMapper

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, modelmapper

I'm trying to make some UnitTest and I've a method like this;

```
public void processInitialBalances(RequestDTO requestDTO) {
    logger.info("At processInitialBalances");

    // Convert from DTO to Entity
    Balance balance = modelMapper.map(requestDTO.getInitialBalances(), Balance.class);

    balance.setId(DUMMY_ID);
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Issuer>>() {}.getType();
    List<Issuer> issuer = modelMapper.map(requestDTO.getInitialBalances().getIssuers(), listType, "issuer-list");

    if (!issuer.isEmpty()) {
        issuer.get(ibcConstants.ZERO).setId(DUMMY_ID);

    balance.setIssuer(issuer);

    // Save balance entity and childs (issuers)
    balance = balanceRepository.save(balance);

    logger.info("Leaving processInitialBalances");
}
```

I'm struggling to pass this line in the UnitTest;

```
    Balance balance = modelMapper.map(requestDTO.getInitialBalances(), Balance.class);

    balance.setId(DUMMY_ID);
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Issuer>>() {}.getType();
    List<Issuer> issuer = modelMapper.map(requestDTO.getInitialBalances().getIssuers(), listType, "issuer-list");
```

Because when I run the classUnderTest.processInitialBalances(dto); I get a NPE at the line balance.setId(id);

I tried to mock the modelMapper but I get a PotentiallyStubbingProblem, here is my test.

```
    @Test
    public void testBalanceCreated() throws ServiceException {
        RequestDTO requestDTO = new RequestDTO();
        BalanceDTO balanceDTO = new BalanceDTO();
        List<IssuerDTO> issuers = new ArrayList<>();
        IssuerDTO issuer = new IssuerDTO();

        issuer.setIssuerName("GBM");
        issuer.setSharePrice(10f);
        issuer.setTotalShares(100);
        issuers.add(issuer);

        balanceDTO.setCash(100f);
        balanceDTO.setIssuers(issuers);

        requestDTO.setInitialBalances(balanceDTO);

        when(modelMapper.map(null, null, null)).thenReturn(new Balance());
        when(modelMapper.map(null, null)).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Issuer>());

        cut.processInitialBalances(requestDTO);

        // Assert entities and repository call.
    }
```

Any advice would be appreciate.

Comment: I tried using Spy on classUnderTest and mocelMapper but still haven't nailed it.

Comment: Even asserting the call to the repository would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

```java
when(modelMapper.map(isNull(), isNull(), isNull())).thenReturn(new Balance());
when(modelMapper.map(isNull(), isNull())).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Issuer>());
```

Comment: from wich library is _given_?

Comment: mockito. Anyway You should not use `null` right away. Use `isNull()`